# Slow resume from standby in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, standby

I have a Lenovo W520 with 10GB of RAM with a super fast SSD drive. The computer cold boots in about 20 seconds, but takes more than 40 seconds to resume from hibernation.

I looked into the event Viewer under Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Diagnostics-Performance and there is an error for every resume I've done, followed by 2-4 warnings. Each warning explains how a specific driver "caused a delay during standby while servicing a device".

The funny part is that on each resume there are a different drivers causing the delays and also the delay times are in the milliseconds (20 - 6000 ms).

I have a feeling there is an even deeper problem that is causing some drivers to take more than usual to start. What else can I do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Are the drivers totally at random or are there two or three that re occur ?, if it is only a few, I would try first of all to update the drivers to the latest version just to rule that one out.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not a driver problem.

The problem is that you have a lot RAM. All the RAM must be written to your SSD before hibernation and again being loaded when you resume from hibernation.

If you just restart your PC, only the minimal Windows configuration is going to be reloaded.
I recommend to just use the sleep option.

Comment: No, "all RAM" doesn't have to be written to the hiberfile, just the parts that are actually used, i.e. what windows cannot throw away. File-cache or code that's backed by a .exe/.dll image can just be discarded. That frees up a lot of RAM. And free RAM obviously doesn't have to be written to the hiberfile.